# Issue with slick carousel (not rendering properly first slide on initial load)

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I switched from react-slick (which worked like a charm) to jQuery original version and while I'm initializing carousel exactly the same way I did, slick fails to render the first slide properly after initial page load. After you select second slide, it works OK. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLCp3.png) and then it loads the background-image and the text you see jumps to the right.

I tried to make it work using

```
$('.your-element').slick('setPosition');
```

after slick initialization and even with setTimeout as suggested [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3166) it takes a second to load properly which is not a solution. I tried to lazy load the carousel and setting display:none for it before I initialize slick but it didn't help me either.

In my html file carousel is being initialized like so:

```
  <section id="carousel">
      <div class="your-class">
        <div class="banner"> // first slide
             <div class="bg"></div> // that's the background-image
             <div class="flex-container">
                 <div class="flex-item">
                     <h1 class="slide__title">Title</h1>
                     <p class="slide__paragraph">
                        text
                     </p>
                     <p class="slide__paragraph">
                        text
                     </p>
                      <p class="slide__paragraph">
                         text
                      </p>
                     <p class="slide__paragraph">
                         text
                     </p>
                     <a>
                       More
                     </a>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>

         <div class="image-grid"> // second slide
                <div class="image01"></div>
                <div class="image02"></div>
                <div class="image03"></div>
                <div class="image04"></div>
                <div class="image05"></div>
                <div class="image06"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

I want my carousel background and text to load simultaneously without text jumping from middle to the side. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Instead of js pass settings in html itself and load slick.js and slick.css before the html.

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
      <div><h3>1</h3></div>
      <div><h3>2</h3></div>
      <div><h3>3</h3></div>
      <div><h3>4</h3></div>
      <div><h3>5</h3></div>
      <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried to do the way you suggested, and my slick.css & slick.js are loaded in <head>, but unfortunately it didn't work, the carousel is not initializing..

Comment: by the way they say I still need to add $(element).slick() to initialize slick on the element, but it didn't work too

Comment: Add jquery before your slick js

Comment: I've managed to fix it another way, but anyway thank you for your quick response

Comment: @max Can you provide your solution in the results

Comment: @Rob i don't recall exactly what i did but the working website is here http://zannadubska.innvationlab.com/?locale=en

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following;
first set up my carousel to have display: none attribute by default; then in js file

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#carousel').attr("style","display: block");
        $('.your-class').slick({
           ....
        });
        }, 200);
};
```

so I went with it